# Debian 9, libm and "symbol __get_cpu_features, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined"

Tags: linux, debian

My software is compiled in Debian 8. On Debian 9 I get this error.

Error info:

```
my_dir/lib/libm.so.6: symbol __get_cpu_features, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not
defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference
```

Is there any suggest on this issue?

Comment: Bundling libm is a bad idea. What happens if you delete `my_dir/lib/libm.*` and let it use the system's libm?

Comment: *"Is there any suggest on this issue?"* - Rename your local copy of `libm` as discussed at [symbol __get_cpu_features, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file libc.so.6 with link time reference](https://github.com/COMBINE-lab/salmon/issues/290).